# php5-mysql install, error 404 Not Found

Tags: apt, package-management, powerpc

I get this message when I try to install `php5-mysql`

> http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/p/php5/php5-mysql_5.3.3-1ubuntu9.7_powerpc.deb 404  Not Found

It's the same when I try both the Ubuntu software center and `apt-get install`

So it seams like the .deb file doesn't exist.

Any idea on how I can install the php5-mysql package? I'm using a powerPC.

(btw, I have the same problem with phpmyadmin, the package doesn't exist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is there, only it is another version. It is also present on the release index

> -rw-r--r-- 1 lp_publish lp_publish    70366 Aug 26 01:03 php5-mysql_5.3.6-13ubuntu3.1_powerpc.deb

This is probably old apt indexes, you need to download them again, open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Make sure that your package list is updated before trying to install software.