# Cannot found compizconfig package

Tags: installation, 12.10, compiz, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update Manager reports a “404 - Failed to fetch” for a deb file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147422/update-manager-reports-a-404-failed-to-fetch-for-a-deb-file)

I tried to install on software center but can't found package:

```
Failed to fetch
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/compiz/python-compizconfig_0.9.8.4+bzr3407-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80] Failed to fetch
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/compiz/compizconfig-settings-manager_0.9.8.4+bzr3407-0ubuntu1_all.deb
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
```

and I tried on terminal have problem to :(

```
myuser@ubuntu:~$ sudo aptitude install compizconfig-settings-manager
[sudo] password for myuser: 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  compizconfig-settings-manager python-compizconfig{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 151 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,152 kB of archives. After unpacking 4,787 kB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/universe python-compizconfig i386 1:0.9.8.4+bzr3407-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/universe compizconfig-settings-manager all 1:0.9.8.4+bzr3407-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
0% [Working]E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/compiz/python-compizconfig_0.9.8.4+bzr3407-0ubuntu1_i386.deb: 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
```

[404] why ? how i can solve this problem ?

I tried without VPN and with VPN .

Comment: Can you try to run `sudo apt-get update` and then re-run the install commands? You seem to have outdated lists. For example `python-compizconfig` should be version `1:0.9.8.6-0ubuntu1` from `quantal-updates` per [the packages.ubuntu.com page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal-updates/python-compizconfig).

Comment: Possible duplicates: [php5-mysql install, error 404 Not Found](http://askubuntu.com/q/105580/88802), [Installing mysql-server on 10.04LTS gives “404 Not Found” error](http://askubuntu.com/q/158626/88802)

Comment: @gertvdijk:Thanks man:) ,`sudo apt-get update` solved problem , thank you ,Do you give answer i accept it ?

Comment: Your question is a plain duplicate. I'm not going to answer here as answers should belong in the canonical question, not in a duplicate. I think your question will be closed soon (I voted-to-close it now) :)

Comment: You can check this Q/A on [404 - Failed to fetch][1].


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/147422/update-manager-reports-a-404-failed-to-fetch-for-a-deb-file